# How can I run a workflow with smoke tests to run in PR merge checks and then a workflow with all tests to run after merge to main branch?

Tags: github, circleci

This is the **config.yml** file I have created. It has 2 workflows. *Smoke tests* & *cypress-all-tests*

```
version: 2.1
orbs:
  cypress: cypress-io/cypress@1
workflows:
  pre-merge-run:
    jobs:
      - cypress/run:
          name: Smoke tests
          command: npm run cy:smoke
          filters:
            branches:
              ignore:
                -main
  cypress-all-tests:
    jobs:
      - cypress/run:
          name: All tests
          command: npm run cy:all:tests
          filters:
            branches:
              only:
                - main
```

My intention is to run *Smoke tests* workflow on every pull request before it is merged to the *main* branch. Then run only *cypress-all-tests* workflow once the PR is merged to the *main* branch.

When the config file is run by CircleCI, this is what happens:

Only smoke tests run on the pull request before merge (which is what I want)

BUT

Both the workflows run after the PR is merged to the *main* branch (which is not what I need). Only the workflow *cypress-all-tests* should be running now.

I don't know where am I making the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

So it was a silly mistake!
I just had to put a space between `-` and `main`. You can see the absence of a space in the screenshot below.

[image]